# What broad concepts are involved while designing a real time statistics system?

Tags: database, nosql, real-time

I need to design a real time statistics system for an online advertising project. I would need to store counters for number of impressions of a url, number of clicks, number of keywords displayed per impression etc. The amount of traffic can be assumed to be around 15000 impressions per second, but should be scalable to > 100000 impressions per second. The database operations are obviously highly write intensive, requiring fast,concurrent writes. What sort of database should I use and how would I go about designing the database architecture?

I am a real rookie in this field and am not really sure how to proceed. I dont have too much experience with NoSql databases, and I am not sure if operations of this scale can be achieved with a relational database like MySql or MS SQL Server.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: I havent actually tried implementing anything yet, I am just in the process of designing the system. My problem is, as I have not worked with anything of this scale, I am unable to proceed.I have never worked with distributed databases etc. That is why my question is more in terms of what broad concepts will be involved in designing such a system, so that I can read up on them. I dont need a direct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What sort of database should I use

On average 4-years old desktop PC running Windows, ESENT NoSQL is [capable of 70k inserts/second](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/laurionb/archive/2008/11/07/some-basic-esent-performance-measurements.aspx) (for small records). And it's surely OK doing fast, concurrent writes. It even has the feature "escrow update column" that allows you to update int32 column values without locking a record, i.e. concurrently.

The DB architecture only depends on the exact data you're going to collect.

P.S. Your task sounds like a hard to me. One problem is scalability: you better decide early if you'll going to scale horizontally, i.e. by adding servers. If yes, it'll affect the architecture a lot. Also, how you'll obtain *that* amount of data? A web server is not capable of processing 100k requests/sec.